# Exchange Failover causes .ost issues - hownto avoid

Tags: virtualization, exchange

Using virtual machine for running exchange and backing it up with a mirror virtual machine in case of failure. During testing of failover and fallback We run into an issue when we fail over the local machines with .ost file connects tto redundant server without issue and send and receive is fine. The problem is when we bring the original server back upoutlook won't sync any new mail to the ost. I have been searching for some method to just force a sync but notfindg anything. The problem is that if people have made changes to their local email or calendar than just deleting and creating a new .ost.

How can I merge in any possible local email? 
calendar,etc in case the user had made changes l

.
.

Comment: Can you tell us what failover/failback method or mechanism you're using?

Comment: I am not aware of any simple ways to do this and not sure that bringing a mirrored image up like this is a good way to go.  Having said that, one suggestion would be to move the new items to another folder and then back to the original folder in OL once you are reconnected to the exch box.  This should move them around and Exch would be aware they exist. Another idea is when bringing the BackupVM live, make it the new master and mirror that VM to a new backup image.  Toss the broken one (or restore back what is needed using the database restore tools).  This way the OST won't be out of sync.

Comment: What version of exchange are you using ?
Are you using a VM based failover + Exchange HA Solutions like DAG ?
Please elucidate.